# RequireJS configuration ignored by inline require calls that follow the script tag that loads my app

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I'm using requireJS and I'd like to access a specific module from it. Unfortunately I always receive a 404 message that the module wasn't found.

I include my js file where the path configuration is located like this:

```
<script src="/js/shop2/springen/vendor/require.min.js" data-main="/js/shop2/springen/app" async></script>
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
define('jquery', [], function() {
    return jQuery;
});

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/shop2/springen/',
    paths: {
        'lodash': 'vendor/lodash.min',  
        'Functions': 'app/modules/functions',
        'Search': 'app/modules/search',
        'Comparison': 'app/modules/comparison',
        'Globals': 'app/globals',
        'Init': 'app/init',
        ...
    }
});

// globals get loaded first and are available to all subordered scripts
require(['Globals', 'lodash'], function () {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        if ($('#comparison').length) {

            require(['Comparison'], function (Comparison) {
                Comparison.init();
            });

        } else {

            require(['Init']);

        }

    });

});
```

Now my problem is that I need to setup my search module inline as I have to generate translations on the server side and initialize it with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    require(['Search'], function () {
        $('#q').shopIncrementalSearch({
            resultsDiv: $('#lifesearch'),
            defaultTitle: 'drücken Sie die Eingabetaste, um',
            defaultText: 'Alle Ergebnisse anzeigen',
            searchingText: 'Suche ...',
            dataUrl: 'http://SRV-CACHE01',
            language: 'de',
            countryId: 1,
            portalId: 22,
            isErpPortal: false,
            sectorId: null
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately I get an error message saying the file wasn't found. Shouldn't I be able to access the requireJS modules when the DOM's ready? Curiously the path of all loaded modules (some modules don't get loaded due to the JS error I guess) are set correctly. Just the Search module looks like this: `/js/shop2/springen/Search.js 404 (Not Found)`
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've logged following in front of my inline javascript:
`console.log(typeof require);`
and it returns me `function` so require is loaded but the paths aren't set.. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are doing *cannot* work *reliably* because you are loading your RequireJS configuration asynchronously *and* you have synchronous code that depends on this configuration.

Here's what happens:

1. This line:

   ```
   <script src="/js/shop2/springen/vendor/require.min.js" data-main="/js/shop2/springen/app" async></script>
   ```

   causes RequireJS to be loaded and causes RequireJS to schedule an *asynchronous* load for your `/js/shop2/springen/app` module.

   The `async` attribute on this element moreover makes it so that the browser is authorized to load RequireJS asynchronously. If it does load RequireJS asynchronously, this compounds the problem you are experiencing because by the time your other `<script>` element is run, there's no telling whether RequireJS is loaded. It may or may not be loaded depending on a bunch of external factors. It boils down to luck. Removing it, however, is not the whole solution because the module you ask be loaded through [`data-main`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) is *still* loaded asynchronously, no matter what.
2. When this is executed:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       require(['Search'], function () {
         ...
       });
     });
   </script>
   ```

   there is no telling whether your main module has loaded or not, because (see above) it is loaded asynchronously. So RequireJS may indeed be *loaded* but it may not have yet been *configured*, because your configuration is located in a module which may or may not be loaded by the time this script is run. This is why `typeof require` would be a function but you'd get errors trying to load modules that depend on your configuration.

   `$(document).ready` does not help because the event which causes `$(document).ready` to fire can happen before RequireJS has loaded the main module.

If you cannot put the `require(['Search']...` code in your main module, what you could do is remove the call to `requirejs.config` from `/js/shop2/springen/app`, and then add a `<script>` element just before the one that loads RequireJS that does:

```
require = {
    baseUrl: '/js/shop2/springen/',
    paths: {
        'lodash': 'vendor/lodash.min',  
        ...
    }
});
```

Setting a [`require` variable](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) to a configuration before RequireJS is loaded tells RequireJS to use the value of this variable as its configuration.

And remember to remove that `async` attribute from the `<script>` that loads RequireJS.

Comment: How does this force the 'inline require to search module logic' to wait for the Search module to be loaded? My main js file includes the 'requirejs.config' object and a single define call with jquery included so that it's loaded as a sitewide utility. If someone was to add a script tag to a page with a jquery selector, could i prevent it from executing until the mainjs loads jquery?